# Checking for horizontal, vertical and diagonal pairs given coordinates

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the slope given a set of points (queenx, queeny with the index number) to find out if two points are horizontal, vertical, or diagonal to each other. Here is the following code:

Note that the method checkSlope simply calculates the slope. I don't understand what's wrong with this method, given the following points:
[0, 0] [6, 1] [4, 2] [7, 3] [1, 4] [3, 5] [5, 6] [2, 7], it still shows that there is match, when there really isn't.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int x1 = queenx.get(i);
        int y1 = queeny.get(i);

        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            int x2 = queenx.get(j);
            int y2 = queeny.get(j);

            if(i != j) {
                double slope = Math.abs(checkSlope(x1, y1, x2, y2));
                try {
                    if ((slope == 1) || (slope == 0)) {
                        correct = false;
                        System.out.println("x1 = " + x1 + " y1 = " + y1 + " x2 = " + x2 + " y2 = " + y2);
                        break;
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    correct = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

   public static double checkSlope(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
       return (double)((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1));
   }
```

Comment: Could you explain what does checkSlope and how you define "Slope"

Comment: Please show us the `checkSlope` function. What does `slope == 1` and `slope == 0` mean? And what case is "correct"?

Comment: @ModusTollens Added the function to the code

Comment: I check if the slope is 1 or 0 because if it's 1, it would mean a diagonal match whereas if it's 0, it means a horizontal match. The Boolean variable correct is a way to mark if there has been one or more vertical, horizontal or diagonal matches. It is initially set as true, to say that there are no matches.

Comment: @PascalHeraud Slope is (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)

Comment: Something is wrong with the checkSlope function I believe. I don't know what though... It seems right to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're converting to double too late. The division is using integers.  Try removing the outer parens: `(double)(y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)`;

But that's a hard way to do it. Also, floating point computations are tricky, as you you've learned. E.g. the slope computation will fail if the denominator is zero.

A simpler way: There are 4 cases:

- On the same horizontal line: `y1 == y2`
- On the same vertical line: `x1 == x2`
- On the same positive slope diagonal: `y2 - y1 == x2 - x1`
- On the same negative slope diagonal: `y2 - y1 == x1 - x2`

You just need to test these four cases.  You can make things neat by factoring differences:

```
int dy = y2 - y1;
int dx = x2 - x1;
if (dx == 0 || dy == 0 || dx == dy || dx == -dy) {
  // match!
}
```

If you like, you can replace  the last two "or" cases with one: `abs(dx) == abs(dy)`.

Comment: How would I fix my current method?

Comment: See new addition, but note it will still fail if the denominator is zero. Slope is the wrong tool here. That's fine. Programming often requires trying different approaches before finding the best.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at https://open.kattis.com/submissions/1599632, it says I have an unhandled exception

Comment: About the code `int dy = y2 = y1;`, Did you mean `int dy = y2 - y1;`

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 0):

point 1 = (x,y) point2 = (a,b)
checking for diagonals:

1. x+y ==  a+b
2. a-b == x-y (take absolute values)

along same horizontal line : y ==b
along same vertical line : x==a